# Writing out items in an array results in commas after each item

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im printing out items in an array in an HTML list:

```
"use strict";

var giftArray = ["kettle", "iron", "bed", "tv", "lamp"];
var gifts = function() {
  var values= [];
  for (var i = 0; i < giftArray.length; i++) {
    values.push("<li>" + giftArray[i] + "</li>");
  }
  document.write("<ul>" + values + "</ul>");
}

gifts();
```

Its working except that it includes a comma after each result. Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you concatenate an array with a string you get the default array `.toString()` representation, which is all the elements joined with commas.

Use [the `.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join all of the elements of the array with the separator of your choice, e.g., with an empty string:

```js
var giftArray = ["kettle", "iron", "bed", "tv", "lamp"];
var gifts = function() {
  var values= [];
  for (var i = 0; i < giftArray.length; i++) {
    values.push("<li>" + giftArray[i] + "</li>");
  }
  document.write("<ul>" + values.join("") + "</ul>");
}

gifts();
```

Or you can use `.join()` instead of your loop, to join your original `giftArray` with appropriate HTML tags:

```js
var giftArray = ["kettle", "iron", "bed", "tv", "lamp"];
var gifts = function() {
  document.write("<ul><li>" + giftArray.join("</li><li>") + "</li></ul>");
}

gifts();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use join() with an empty string as delimiter

```
document.write("<ul>" + values.join('') + "</ul>");
```

The default when writng an array into dom is to convert it to string using `Array.prototype.toString()` which includes the comma delimter